# tikz arrow tips, or a symbol with ->|, |-<, <-i shape, for the enter, indentation and de-indentation keys on the keyboard

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

The grammar of Python and other languages that use indentation for blocking, includes derivation such as

```
Block ::= NewLine Indent Statemetns DeIndent
```

I would like to write such a rule in my document.

I am trying to depict the tab and backtab key as shown
[image]

For the enter key

[image]

I found in [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) the mathematical symbol `\hookleftarrow` which could be thought of as an approximation.

I can do something like tikz, but I wonder if anyone knows of a premade solution?

Comment: Do you want the key picture or only the arrows?

Comment: These arrows all exist in the `arrows.meta` library and are called `Bar` and `Triangle` etc.

Comment: @Sigur: just the arrows.

Comment: I guess I was not precise enough. I was looking for characters in a font. I should probably rephrase

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if these symbols are predefined in some package, most likely they are. Yet it is straightforward to build your own.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\TikzTab}{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.1em,{-Triangle[]  Bar[]}] 
(0,0) -- (1.2em,0);}}
\newcommand{\TikzBTab}{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.1em,{Bar[] Triangle[]  -}] 
(0,0) -- (1.2em,0);}}
\newcommand{\TikzReturn}{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.1em,{-Triangle[]}] 
(0,0) |- (-1em,-0.4em);}}
\begin{document}
ABC \TikzTab\ DEF \TikzBTab\ GHI \TikzReturn\ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a version for Joule V. (Thanks!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\TikzTab}{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.1em,
-{Triangle[length=0.33em] Bar[]}] 
(0,0) -- (1.2em,0);}}
\newcommand{\TikzBTab}{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.1em,{Bar[]
Triangle[length=0.33em]}-] 
(0,0) -- (1.2em,0);}}
\newcommand{\TikzReturn}{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.1em,-{Triangle[length=0.33em]}] 
(0,0) |- (-1em,-0.4em);}}
\begin{document}
ABC \TikzTab\ DEF \TikzBTab\ GHI \TikzReturn\ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JouleV Thanks! Better now?

Comment: It is at its best now :-)